# How to get the node from the url referer?

Tags: 8, theming, entities

I have a custom entity named **Application** that has an **Entity Reference** field named **Product**.

When I am on an Apllication page and click on a **Product** to see it, I would like to know that I come from the **Application** page and know its **ID**.

This would allow me to display information from the **Application** page on the **Product** page.

But how to do it ?

Comment: The information will need to be displayed only when one comes from application page or anyone who visits product will see the associated application info ?

Comment: Only when someone comes from the application page to the product page.

Comment: There might be a new module which can do that: https://www.drupal.org/project/referer_to_entity_reference

Comment: Did my answer help you? maybe you can consider checking it as accepted.

Answer (score 10):

This method works for me:

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Drupal\Core\Url;
// Getting the referer.
$request = \Drupal::request();
$referer = $request->headers->get('referer');
// Getting the base url.
$base_url = Request::createFromGlobals()->getSchemeAndHttpHost();
// Getting the alias or the relative path.
$alias = substr($referer, strlen($base_url));
// Getting the node.
$params = Url::fromUri("internal:" . $alias)->getRouteParameters();
$entity_type = key($params);
$node = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage($entity_type)->load($params[$entity_type]);

// To use dpm you need the devel module.
dpm($node->id());
dpm($node->title->value);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$previousUrl = \Drupal::request()->server->get('HTTP_REFERER');
$fake_request = Request::create($previousUrl);
$url_object = \Drupal::service('path.validator')->getUrlIfValid($fake_request->getRequestUri());
$route_name = $url_object->getRouteName();
$url = Url::fromRoute($route_name, $url_object->getRouteParameters());
$previousPath = $url->getInternalPath();
```